# Javascript nested functions initialization

Tags: javascript, performance, closures

I have a javascript function which contains another javascript function inside (closure)

```
function function1() {
    $("button").bind("click", function () {
        function2();
    });

    function function2() {
        // code
    };
};
```

My question:

When i call function1() for many times, does the function2() gets created each time (and saved in memory)? or it is shared?

`function1` is not used as a constructor, so i don't think i should use `prototype`

Comment: yes the function is created every time but gets destroyed after execution of the function1() hence not present in the memory after execution of the function1. I would use firebug to check the same

Comment: How can i check this with firebug?

Comment: it's a firefox plugin. Just google it. You'll find it

Comment: I do use firebug a lot, but didn't knew how to check for js memory. I think you talk about firebug profiler

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal no the function will not disappear. It will only disappear when the jQuery event handler is cleared (implicitly removes the $.cache reference to the anonomyous function which in turn keeps alive function2 from closure). After function1 returns, the unique function2 that was just created is easily available even to you as user from `window.$.cache[xx].events.click[0].handler` so destroying it would be pretty dangerous :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `function2` would be created each time `function1` is executed, which is possibly an avoidable inefficiency.

The code in the question would execute more efficiently as follows :

```
function function2() {
    // code
};
function function1() {
    $("button").bind("click", function2);
};
```

Thus, `function2` is defined once and used, potentially, many times over.

The price you pay for this efficiency is to deny `function2` the opportunity of accessing any vars declared inside `function1`. As given, no such vars exist, so you would be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call function1, a new function2 is created and saved in memory, and is signed up as part of a click handler.

The function2's that are created by function1 can't get garbage collected as long as they could potentially be called through your click handler.

Comment: Removing the element from DOM using `$.remove()` will allow `function2` to be garbage collected?

Comment: I don't know whether `$.remove()` allows `function2` to be garbage collected in browser implementations.  I would expect it to, because otherwise it would be a memory leak.

Comment: @RaraituL: Yes, removing the element from DOM will cause `function2` to be garbage collected in all browsers. In IE versions less than 7 `function2` will not be garbage collected if it contains references to the element since IE7 and below had a bug that couldn't garbage collect circular references if those references lead to the DOM. Regular, non-DOM circular references are garbage collectible. Most libraries like YUI and jQuery has functions that recursively removes event handlers on DOM elements for exactly this reason.

Comment: @RaraituL: Hmm.. reading from the docs: http://api.jquery.com/remove/. It looks like jQuery `.remove()` unbinds all event handlers recursively before removing the element from DOM. So jQuery already handles that for you. So the answer is yes, jQuery's `remove()` will make `function2` be garbage collected.