# Do nested functions of Javscript get defined everytime the nesting functions get called?

Tags: javascript, performance

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251479/javascript-nested-functions-initialization) question, I found nested functions created each time the nesting functions get called as I expected. But the word 'create' doesn't make it clear about this question. Do Javascript engines have to interpret the **definition** of the nested functions everytime as well? I'm asking this question in wondering if the engines save the definition of a nested function somewhere and will return a function bound with some variables that are used in the nested function like below code does.

```
class A {
    functionForInstance = this.sharedDefinition.bind(this);

    sharedDefinition() {
        return this.someField;
    }
}
```

**One more question**

According to @Jose Marin's answer, engines create closures(instances) from saved function definitions. Then does it also apply to arrow functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Engines doesn't need to interpret the definition of the nested functions every-time.

Functions are read only object, then once defined they can be reuse any time.

You are pointing something that could confuse people. Function execution is control in the call stack, and you could find the same function being called several times and using different closure. But they all share the same definition outside of the call stack.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to see the same nested function on the call stack repeatedly, but it doesn't imply that it is created in memory only once. General objects defined in local scope of a function are inaccessible after the end of functions's execution and as such can be garbage-collected. Couldn't it be also the case of a nested function, which may need to be created again after garbage collection? I don't have knowledge how JS engines work, I'm just asking for more evidence. :-)

Comment: Yeah @Jose Marin said that everytime a nesting function gets called, the closure(or instance) of the nested function will get created. And of course GC will have to work more in the structure than in the class structure I showed in my question. My question is from a part of consideration in choosing between class component and functional component, and I found that there aren't many cases where functional component is better than class one.

Comment: I added one more question in my question. Would you answer about it?

Comment: I don't know with total certainty, though tend to think it applies to arrow functions as well. The engine - being v8 the most popular - is not going to forget what it just slowly executed to start again with the optimized version. Instead, it will transform all the context we have (stack, registers) so that we can switch to the optimized version in the middle of the execution. Take a look to this link: https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-inside-the-v8-engine-5-tips-on-how-to-write-optimized-code-ac089e62b12e#47e8

Answer (score 1):

There may be a performance drawback when using nested functions, because each time the outer function is called, new closure for the nested function will be created. If working with objects, it could be fixed by defining the function on object prototype instead of nesting.

See this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#performance_considerations) on closures for more info and examples.